# Automated taxonomic identification of insects – where can I find some good enough software or code?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, image-classification

Short context: my colleagues study plant-pollinator networks. Insect (pollinator) identification is a task that requires a lot of effort.

**I would like to know if there are already trained or trainable models with good accuracy used to identify pollinators (insects) from mobile phone images taken in the field (possibly, a close-up photo of the insect on a flower). Identification to family level would be good enough for their research.** Maybe for some easy to identify insects, identification to specie level would be also possible.

Note that, I could find few research articles that provide code (e.g. a GitHub repository with the model and workflows), but they are mostly focused on using sharp, good quality, close-up images taken in the lab from insect collections, with the goal to identify insects to species level, e.g:

1. Valan, 2019 - Automated Taxonomic Identification of Insects with
   Expert-Level Accuracy Using Effective Feature Transfer from
   Convolutional Networks
   https://github.com/valanm/off-the-shelf-insect-identification
2. Buschbacher, 2020- Image-based species identification of wild bees    using convolutional neural networks,
   https://deepabis.github.io/,    https://github.com/deepabis/deepabis

Valan (2019) presents a great illustration (below) about the increase in difficulty of such classification. This might get even harder when it comes to using mobile phone photos from the field with a lot of background noise.

[image]

I also asked this question on [research gate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Automated_taxonomic_identification_of_insects-where_can_I_find_some_good_enough_software_or_code), but I think it might be interesting to have it on this platform too.